# Markers in seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
from cycler import cycler
markers = cycler(marker=['*', 'o'] * 100)

g = sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', df, fit_reg=False, hue='z', lowess=True, scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, legend=True, markers=markers)
```

In the code above, I want to cycle through markers. However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Cycler'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `markers=['*', 'o']`.

The `markers` argument in `lmplot()` requires a single entry for each level of `hue`.  You can test this:

```
N = 100
data = {"x":np.random.random(N),
        "y":np.random.random(N),
        "z":np.random.choice([0,1], size=N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

markers = [1,2,3]

g = sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='z', lowess=True, 
               scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, legend=True, markers=markers)
```

^ This will throw an error:

> ValueError: markers must be a singeton or a list of markers for each level of the hue variable

If this is the only use case for importing the (rather esoteric) `cycler` module, you're better off leaving it out and simply defining the markers you want bound to your `z` column.

As for the actual error you posted, note that each element in `markers` is a `dict`.  There's a `marker` field that will get the actual `marker` character.  You can see this with:

```
for m in markers:
    print(m['marker'])
```

Comment: thanks! so I do get that error you describe. what do you mean by `simply defining the markers you want bound to your z column`?

Comment: Change the `markers` argument to `markers=['*', 'o']`.

Comment: You only had two distinct markers defined in your post.  How many levels of `z` exist?

Comment: Ah ok, `z` levels are 12. but they can change, do `z` levels need to match number of markers?

Comment: Yes, see the `ValueError` text, "markers must be ... a list of markers for each level of the hue variable".  Within a single dataset, just include markers for the max number of `z` levels.  If you're iterating over multiple datasets, you'll have to identify the levels of `z` dynamically and set marker arrays for each.  This is far afield of your original question - if you have trouble getting the multi-dataset case to work, open a new question.